# python pip defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable

Tags: ubuntu, pip, virtualenv, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am setting up a clean version of Ubuntu under WSL2, it needs to run python 3.7 because of some dependencies. The goal is to have a project folder with a virtual environment in it, and to be able to install packages into the venv.

The sequence of commands I use to set up the environment is

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install python3.7
sudo apt install python3-pip
sudo apt install python3-virtualenv
```

Everything works up to the point where I try and install a package into the venv. The commands are

```
cd ./OneDrive/dev/babyclix_stg
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.7 .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
pip3 install requests
```

The last pip3 command then returns this exception/error message.

```
(.venv) dev@DESKTOP-6FAUQ4D:/mnt/c/Users/mark/OneDrive/dev/babyclix_stg$ pip3 install requests
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (2.22.0)
```

My venv, which created successfully has this structure.

[image: venv folder structure]

I am obviously doing something basic incorrectly. Can someone please point out my error.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `sudo pip3 install requests`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
python3 -m pip install requests
```